SharePoint Theme Hyperlink Text Color
Our Marketing team is asking us to add a SharePoint theme using the Dark Blue theme as a basis but change the accent and other blues on the page to use a specific blue #0c34eb.  I referenced Where can I get the colors for the built-in themes for SharePoint Online? to get the baseline and it's pretty much what I want.
However, when using the blue from our Marketing team the Link Text is barely readable.  Is there a way to force that text to be White or some other color to make it easier to read?  Below is what I see when I load the theme with our blue and the PowerShell command for the theme:
$themeDark=@{
"themePrimary"="#0c34eb";
"themeLighterAlt"="#00090c";
"themeLighter"="#001318";
"themeLight"="#002630";
"themeTertiary"="#005066";
"themeSecondary"="#00abda";
"themeDarkAlt"="#0ecbff";
"themeDark"="#0c34eb";
"themeDarker"="#6cdfff";
"neutralLighterAlt"="#2e3340";
"neutralLighter"="#353a49";
"neutralLight"="#404759";
"neutralQuaternaryAlt"="#474e62";
"neutralQuaternary"="#4c546a";
"neutralTertiaryAlt"="#646e8a";
"neutralTertiary"="#c8c8c8";
"neutralSecondaryAlt"="#d0d0d0";
"neutralSecondary"="#dadada";
"neutralPrimaryAlt"="#eaeaea";
"neutralPrimary"="#ffffff";
"neutralDark"="#f4f4f4";
"black"="#f8f8f8";
"white"="#262a35";
"primaryBackground"="#262a35";
"primaryText"="#ffffff";
"error"="#ff5f5f";
"accent"="#0c34eb";
"AccentText"="#ffffff";
"TopBarPressedText"="#ffffff";                            
"HeaderNavigationPressedText"="#ffffff";                                        
"HeaderNavigationHoverText"="#ffffff";
"HeaderNavigationSelectedText"="#ffffff";
"Hyperlink"="#ffffff";                    
"AccentLines"="#ffffff";
"HeaderAccentLines"="#ffffff";                      
"SuiteBarHoverText"="#ffffff";
"EmphasisText"="#ffffff";
"SuiteBarText"="#ffffff";
"TileText"="#ffffff";
"Lines"="#ffffff";                
"HeaderLines"="#ffffff";
"ButtonBorder"="#ffffff";
"CommandLinks"="#ffffff";
"Navigation"="#ffffff";
"SubtleEmphasisText"="#ffffff";
"TopBarText"="#ffffff";
"HeaderNavigationText"="#ffffff";
"ButtonGlyph"="#ffffff";
"BodyText"="#ffffff";
"WebPartHeading"="#ffffff";
"HeaderText"="#ffffff";
"ButtonText"="#ffffff";
"ButtonGlyphActive"="#ffffff";
"TopBarHoverText"="#ffffff";
"StrongBodyText"="#ffffff";
"SiteTitle"="#ffffff";
"CommandLinksSecondary"="#ffffff";
"SubtleEmphasisCommandLinks"="#ffffff";
"HeaderSiteTitle"="#ffffff";
}



This is a coding site. Unless you want help writing custom CSS, for example, you should probably engage a SharePoint support community instead.
